# Javascript Error "Missing ; before statement"

Tags: javascript

I am having a very weird error on this block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var captions = new Array();
  captions[0] = "";
  captions[1] = '<div class="cap-desc"><h3>No Win - No Fee</h3><span class="captionSubhead">Performance Guarantee</span><br /><span style="color:#636363; font-size:13px;">Ask Today. We are very confident<br />you'll be impressed with our results! </span></div><br /><a href="http://#" class="rmore" target="_blank">read more</a>';
</script>
```

The error tells me that I am missing a ';' before captions[1] but I am pretty sure that captions[0] has a semi-colon!

The whole site is here: http://katron.sourcefit.com/cms02/a&a/

It has 5 captions now, but same error nonetheless. I tried changing the contents of the caption in question. In this case, it's captions[1] and it works. What is wrong with the caption? I am sure I am closing all tags and quotes and escaping \n to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not escaping a single quote properly...

```
captions[1] = '<div class="cap-desc"><h3>No Win - No Fee</h3><span class="captionSubhead">Performance Guarantee</span><br /><span style="color:#636363; font-size:13px;">Ask Today. We are very confident<br />you\'ll be impressed with our results! </span></div><br /><a href="http://#" class="rmore" target="_blank">read more</a>';
```

This just escapes the apostrophe in

> you'll

Comment: it's funny because stack overflow syntax highlighting already highlighted his error

Answer (score 5):

The problem is `you'll` has an apostrophe and ends the code block. Make sure to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question when I was googling the error.

My solution is not relevant to the original post but may help someone anyway.

I had forgotten the word `function` after a declaration:

```
Foo.bar(evt) {
    ...
}
```

should have been

```
Foo.bar = function(evt) {
    ...
}
```

Took me a little while to find this bug, so hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The same error can occur if you are trying to add a property to an existing object prefixing with a var. For example

```
var existingObject = {};

var existingObject.property1 = {}; //will throw the same error
```

The solution is:

```
var existingObject = {};

existingObject.property1 = {}; //without prefixing with var
```

Comment: Ha! This was the reason for my error! Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of single quote in last line at  `confident
you'll be impressed` repalce it with `\'` and it think that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

> you'll be impressed with our results!

That apostrophe (') in you'll is ending your string. So the javascript engine is looking for a semicolon there.

replace with \' to escape it

Answer (score 0):

Check "you'll be impressed with our results! " in your captions[1] it has ' character which does not have escape character.